# Remove a specific class from an element in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to remove a class from a nested element in HTML.

`<div class=sample>`

`<p>This should have the class as sample</p>`

`<p>This should not have the class as sample</p>`

`</div>`

In the above snippet, I dont want to let the second `<p>` element to have the class sample. How can i do so?

Comment: You probably got downvoted because of a lack of details and you appear to not have made any attempts at solving this yourself.

Comment: I did try solving on my own, and I even got one, that's, give a separate class to the second <p> element, and reverse the change, but that's a headache, so waiting for some better way to sort it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might like to try playing with the `:not` pseudo selector combined with `:nth-child`

```css
.sample > p:not(:nth-child(2)){
  color:red;
  background:yellow
}
```

```html
<div class='sample'>

  <p>This should have the class as sample</p>

  <p>This should not have the class as sample</p>

</div>
```

Comment: That did the task, thank you 

Comment: My pleasure - Happy New Year

Comment: Same to You, Happy New Year